# Motion blur interfering with animation and camera

Tags: animation, motion-blur

Motion blur is doing something wierd.

I like to create my animations all in one file and all in one render. That means when I switch the cameras and characters to a new location every time I do a new shot, which happens within the time of 2 frames, the motion blur option takes this into account and blurs the 2 frames like crazy.
image right before/after a different shot
[image: image right before/after different shot]
normal image without motion blur
[image: normal image without motion blur]
image right before/after a different shot
[image: image right before/after different shot]

normal image without motion blur

[image: normal image without motion blur]

Is there a way to tell the motion blur option that I don't want motion blur on certain frames?

Comment: Are you using one camera and instantaneously moving it back-and-forth?

Comment: I use to do that, and the same problem would occur, but now I use multiple cameras. However, I am moving a lot of props and things instantaneously.